# C-Making a Matrix in Echelon Form?

Tags: c, arrays, forms, matrix, ref

> Hey, so I wanted to make a program for making a Matrix in Echelon form(Not Reduced Echelon Form). Everything seems to be working fine except when the last element of the matrix is 0. That time, it just divides the row and makes it 1! 
>   So, I added a while loop to fix that but it still doesn't work since the while loop is not getting executed! Could anyone tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void Interchange(float A[][3],int row_pos,int column_pos,int m);
void RowDivide(float A[][3],int row_pos,int column_pos,int m);
void RowOperation(float A[][3],int row_pos,int row_op,int column_pos,int m);



int main()
{
int m;

printf("Enter the number of rows in the Matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&m);

float A[m][3];
printf("\nEnter the Matrix:\n");
for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
}

int column_pos=0;
for(int row_pos=0 ; row_pos<m ; row_pos++)
{
    ///For Interchanging
    if(A[row_pos][column_pos] == 0)
    {
        Interchange(A,row_pos,column_pos,m);
    }

    ///For Row Division
```

> This While Loop doesn't get Executed!!! 
>     I know it's not getting executed cause it doesn't print "a" like I wrote
>     Can anyone tell me as to why?!

```
    while(A[row_pos][column_pos] == 0)
    {
        printf("a");
        column_pos++;
    }
    RowDivide(A,row_pos,column_pos,m);
```

> If the last element over here is 0, it divides it and makes it 1! Why?

```
    ///For Row Operations
    if(row_pos == m-1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int row_op = row_pos+1 ; row_op<m ; row_op++)
        RowOperation(A,row_pos,row_op,column_pos,m);
    }

    column_pos++;
}


printf("\nThe Matrix in Echolen Form:\n");
for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        printf("%0.2f ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}




void Interchange(float A[][3],int row_pos,int column_pos,int m)
{
float temp;
int cal_pos;
cal_pos=row_pos;
while(A[cal_pos][column_pos] == 0)
{
    cal_pos++;
}
for(int i=row_pos ; i<row_pos+1 ; i++)
{
    for(int j=column_pos ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        temp = A[i][j];
        A[i][j] = A[cal_pos][j];
        A[cal_pos][j] =  temp;
    }
}

printf("\nThe Matrix after Interchanging Row %d is:\n",row_pos+1);
for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        printf("%0.2f ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}




void RowDivide(float A[][3],int row_pos,int column_pos,int m)
{
float temp;   ///To store the value of A[i][0] since it will get changed to     1 after dividing

for(int i=row_pos ; i<row_pos+1 ; i++)
{
    temp = A[i][column_pos];
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = (A[i][j] / temp);
    }
}

printf("\nThe Matrix after dividing the Row %d is:\n",row_pos+1);
for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
    {
        printf("%0.2f ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}



void RowOperation(float A[][3],int row_pos,int row_op,int column_pos,int m)
{
float Cal_Operation;    ///For the value of row that must be added

for(int i=row_op ; i<row_op+1 ; i++)
{
    if(A[i][column_pos] == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Cal_Operation = -A[i][column_pos];
        printf("\nCalculated Variable for Row %d=     %0.2f\n",row_op+1,Cal_Operation);
        for(int j=column_pos ; j<3 ; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] + (Cal_Operation*A[row_pos][j]);
        }
        printf("The Matrix after Operating on Row %d is:\n",row_op+1);
        for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
            {
                printf("%0.2f ",A[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are doing, but if you want that while loop to find the first 0 element, you should just change it into:

```
while(A[row_pos][column_pos] != 0)
```

I might have misunderstood your intentions though, let me know if that's the case.

Comment: No, I actually want the while loop to get executed whenever the element is 0. So, I felt that should have worked... But it's not, even when the element is 0, the while loop is not executing tho it should.

Comment: But I still really appreciate your help! So Thank you so much for that! It means a lot! :)

Comment: I found the problem is floating point error: using float numbers that == 0 operation makes little sense, and I suggest you to check, instead, if absolute value of the number is very very little, for example less than 0.00000001 (you should calculate that value, it's based on machine precision).
Import <math.h> for fabs function, then check something like
`while(fabs(A[row_pos][column_pos]) <= 0.00001)`

Comment: I haven't understood what Interchange does yet, but changing the code like i said makes the while actually loop.
Unfortunately I believe this brings more problems, as you can see testing it with simple matrix (like 3x3 (1,3,3,0,0,1,0,0,0))